# R iterating through 1600 cols in df with binary values 0 and 1 and copy values from two other columns to save in an array by group

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix

I have a Dataframe df with 1600 columns named as X1,X2,X3....X1600 based on binary data 0 and 1 values and these 0 and 1 values have corresponding latitude and longitude data in first 2 columns.
I have to iterate through each column of Dataframe with binary values one by one. Taking in to account 1st column I have to group it according to 0 and 1 values and their corresponding latitude and longitude values should be copied to a 2D array or list to be converted into a matrix at later stage.

Using a for loop would not be ideal, is there any simplified method to get this matrix x and y with 2 columns?

My df looks like this:

| Latitude | Longitude | X1 | X2 | X3... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45.65 | 11.54 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 62.87 | 18.17 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 51.30 | 1.10 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

what I want to get on the basis of X1 is:

x:

| Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- |
| 45.65 | 11.54 |
| 51.30 | 1.10 |

y:

| Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- |
| 62.87 | 18.17 |

I need to continue this for all 1600 columns one by one. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your current expected output based on `X1` looks like a named-list with names `$x` and `$y`. Given `X1:X3`, what does the expected output look like?

Comment: @r2evans what matters to me at the end is a matrix ' x ' with latitude and longitude values of 0 and ' y ' with lat and longitude values of 1, which can either be converted from a 2D list or array. I am focusing on a method which is more efficient and solves my problem.

Comment: Your question explicitly cites 1600 columns and you mention "efficient", which means that you want to do all 1600 columns into one object. That one object definitely doesn't look exactly like what you've offered in your question, so I'm asking what your `list(x=matrix(..), y=matrix(..))` looks like when you also include `X2` and `X3`. If you aren't certain what that should look like, then perhaps you can talk about how you will be using this data. BTW, please be explicit with non-base packages; I can infer `%dopar%`, but I don't know `peacock2`. Please don't make us guess. (Is it relevant?)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the comments and suggestions. I have rephrased my question now. Hopefully It helps understanding the problem.

Comment: This seems like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You're basically asking to copy your data 1600 times. Why bother? You can easily extract whatever subset you need from any specific `x` column, with `col = "X1"; y = df[df[[col]] == 1, 1:2]; x = df[df[[col]] == 0, 1:2]`. What's the point in calculating all the subsets in advance? (And if you do really want to do it, what's wrong with a for loop here?)

Comment: @Gregor Thomas Every column X1 and X2 onwards represents a unique SNP and 0 and 1 represent wild type and mutated SNP respectively, hence each column needs to be separately grouped into 0 and 1. And I need x and y matrix for each column to be able to apply statistical method Peacock2. The resulting Pvalue will be copied to a separate column in another table with correlated SNP. When this test is done, then the next column X2 will give same results until 1600 cols.

Comment: Yes, but why copy your data 1600 times first? Why not use a loop over each X# column to {split the data into x and y matrix, apply statistical method peacock 2, store p-value in another table with correlated SNP}. This way you make 1 copy of the Lat/Long data, and overwrite it each time, only keeping what you need. It will be **much** more memory efficient than {make 1600 copies of data}, for each copy {store p-value in another table with correlated SNP}, which keeps all 1600 copies of data at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've explained in comments, I think this is a bad idea. But here is code to do it:

```
m = as.matrix(df[c("Latitude", "Longitude")])
results = lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(x) 
  list(
    x = m[x == 0, , drop = FALSE], 
    y = m[x == 1, , drop = FALSE]
  )
)
names(results) = names(df)[-(1:2)]
```

How I would suggest doing it instead (untested, probably not working code)

```
m = as.matrix(df[c("Latitude", "Longitude")])
cols = names(df)[-(1:2)]
results = list()
for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
  pea_result = peacock2(
    x = m[df[[cols[i]]] == 0, ], 
    y = m[df[[cols[i]]] == 1, ],
    ... # other args for peacock
  )
  results[[cols[i]]] = pea_result$pvalue
  ## alternately, you could make each item of results
  ## a sub-list that records more than just the p value
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the great solution. I really appreciate it. I like your point in above comment ''Why not use a loop over each X# column to {split the data into x and y matrix, apply statistical method peacock 2, store p-value in another table with correlated SNP}''. Is there a way in your above solution I can apply this?

Comment: your solution solved the problem, I am really grateful for the help.